# Divergence theorem to calculate flux through an open cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Calculate the flux of $\vec F=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}(x,y,z)$ through the cylinder
$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3∣x^2+y^2=2,−2\leq z\leq2\}$ by using Gauss Law (divergence theorem).

By calculation I obtain that
$\nabla\cdot\vec F=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}$

I call:

The flux through the closed cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3∣x^2+y^2=2,−2\leq z\leq2\}$ for $C$.

The flux through the bottom plate $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3∣x^2+y^2=2,z=2\}$ for $B$.

The flux trough the top plate $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3∣x^2+y^2=2,z=-2\}$ for $T$.

What I want to calculate is $C-B-T$ which I call $K$.

$$K = \iiint_V\nabla\cdot\vec F \,dx\,dy\,dz - \iint_\text{top}\vec F\cdot\vec n\,dS - \iint_\text{bottom}\vec F\cdot\vec n\,dS$$ with the bounds being the entire cylinder, top face, and bottom face respectively.

$\vec n = (0,0,1)$ for $T$ and $\vec n= (0,0,-1)$ for $B$

$$C = \iiint\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz = \left(\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dxdy\right)\left(\int dz\right) = 4\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dxdy$$ where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=2\}$ is a horizontal cross section of the cylinder.

$$B = \iint_A(0,0,-1)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{-2}{x^2+y^2}\right)dx\,dy = 2\iint_A \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$

$$T = \iint_A (0,0,1)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy = 2\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$

$$K = 4\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy - 2\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dxdy - 2\iint_A\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy = 0$$

But in the end I get $0$, while the answer should be $8\pi$. What went wrong?

Comment: hey there! please have a look at this guide for formatting your questions to make them nice and readable for people who'd like to help: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that the integrals $C, B, T$ are divergent because of the singularity on the $z$ axis. It's actually easier to compute the surface integral directly. If the lateral surface of the cylinder is parametrized as $(\sqrt 2 \cos t, \sqrt 2 \sin t, z)$, then $\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S = dt dz$, which gives the desired result.